# facebook: How do i get the url's to original pictures from public group posts

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an app that reads a public facebook group posts.
I would like to extract not only a specific message ( which comes with the picture property containing a small \ thumb image url) but also but also all images ( original size ).

The message is already done and working, but how do i get the original images belonging to this post?

Comment: How are you doing the message?

Comment: I d not understand exaclty what you mean by that, but i use a token to retrieve the message like this :
https://graph.facebook.com/group_id/feed?limit=5&access_token=rterhvt.....

Comment: Actually as you can see, i don't use a token for open groups  (oops)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/{post_id}/picture?type=<thumbnail OR normal OR album>
```

For example:

Normal: http://graph.facebook.com/1512268202361405/picture?type=normal

Comment: Yea, i tried that with all 3 parameters, still only get the small image, however when i look at the original post in fb, i see a high res image.... below examples are done with the 'normal' setting

facebook original
https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10152933999019380&set=pcb.506207536185584&type=1&relevant_count=4

the one that we retrieved using the graph normal
https://ticosvendemos.com/usario-anuncia/27988

Comment: is it because I am trying to retrieving images from a group and not from a regular profile post ?

Comment: No. That wont affect it! I'm able to retrieve the full sized image using: http://graph.facebook.com/10152933999019380/picture?type=normal

It gives me following image: https://scontent-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xaf1/t31.0-8/s720x720/10556866_10152933999019380_2401342409131840937_o.jpg

Comment: How exactly are you requesting this image? Can you share your code? If you directly make a get request to the Graph URL, it returns a high resolution image.

Comment: Ok, guys... me == noob .... i was using the wrong id... you showing me put me on the right path... thanks, it s working now.